# Are there general parameters in which a traditional machine learning algorithm will outperform a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation

I know this is a loaded question given the infinite number of circumstances surrounding what kind of machine learning algorithm to implement.  I was just wondering if there is a general framework that can hint at a situation in which "regular" machine learning algorithm will certainly outperform a neural net.

Comment: NN is "traditional machine learning". Do you mean to compare it with something more traditionally statistical?

Comment: You can't get more traditional than neural networks. Assuming that you mean _deep neural nets_ vs any other form of ML, then the answer is still a definite _yes_. There's no universally best method.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a normally distributed response with normally distributed features, $E(y|x)$ is **provably** the best minimizer of mean squared predictive error.

See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/problem-with-proof-of-conditional-expectation-as-best-predictor).

Or Bickel and Doksum text "Mathematical Statistics."